# Alt + arrow keys escape sequences in Iterm terminal are not the same in VsCode terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, input, key, escaping

I am trying to read keys from STDIN, and in order to do that I need to know the appropriate escape sequences for every key that I need, but I noticed that the escape sequences of (Alt + any arrow key) in terminal is not the same as in VsCode terminal.

for example (Alt + up arrow) escape sequence in iterm terminal is `\e\e[A` but in VsCode is `\e[1;3A`, with `\e`, `^[`, or `ESC` that is equivalent to `27` in ASCII decimal code.

I just want to know why there is such a difference?, since the other escape sequences of some other keys that I have tried are the same in both of iterm and VsCode terminal, and is there a way to read (Alt + arrow keys) in a different way in order to make my program works the same in both of iterm and Vscode?

this is my main.c that I use to know the escape sequences for keys, and If you don't have time to compile or you just don't feel like, you can run `cat` command line, and then press for example `Alt + right arrow` to see its escape sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
struct termios orig_termios;
void disableRawMode() {
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios);
}
void enableRawMode() {
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios);
  atexit(disableRawMode);
  struct termios raw = orig_termios;
   raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}

int main() {
  enableRawMode();
   while (1) {
    char c = '\0';
    read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
    if (iscntrl(c)) {
      printf("%d\r\n", c);
    } else {
      printf("%d ('%c')\r\n", c, c);
    }
    if (c == 'q') break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Different terminal use different key mappings, that's all. -- Since I don't use VSC, I have no idea how to make its terminal produce the same encoding as your standard terminal.

Comment: @thebusybee thanks, then the only option rest for me is to initialize both of the sequences as a single key.

Comment: Are you using iTerm and VsCode with the same underlying operating system?

Comment: @fpiette yes I am using both of them in MacOS Mojave.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no knowledge of MacOS. On other systems, escape sequences are dependent of the system, not the tool used to build an application. Is it possible that VsCode application use something else that iTerm which looks like an add-on?

Comment: @fpiette that's what I thought, maybe.